# Is it possible to create embeddable tweets in an iOS app through the API without having users log in to Twitter?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter, twitter-oauth

Does the Twitter API expose such functionality? Where I could display a single tweet here and there (this is a link-saving app) and get the information (retweets, tweet text, etc.) of the tweet through the API?

I know I can do this if the user is logged in via OAuth to my app, but what if I just wanted to display a preview of a tweet here and there without making the user log in? Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) [Install Twitter via CocoaPods](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/twitterkit/install)

2) update your ConsumerKey and consumerSecret

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import TwitterKit

var window: UIWindow?
let viewController = ViewController()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window!.rootViewController = self.viewController
    self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

    Twitter.sharedInstance().startWithConsumerKey("################", consumerSecret: "################")

    return true
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import TwitterKit

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    TWTRAPIClient().loadTweetWithID("631879971628183552") { (tweet, error) in

        if let unwrappedTweet = tweet {

            let tweetView = TWTRTweetView()
            tweetView.theme = .Light
            tweetView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            tweetView.primaryTextColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            tweetView.linkTextColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            tweetView.showBorder = false
            tweetView.configureWithTweet(unwrappedTweet)
            tweetView.delegate = self
            let height = TWTRTweetTableViewCell.heightForTweet(unwrappedTweet, width: self.view.bounds.size.width - 40)
            tweetView.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width - 40, height: height)
            tweetView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.view.center.y)
            self.view.addSubview(tweetView)

        } else {
            print("Tweet load error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```